# Tool to rotate screen content without the need to physically rotate the screen?

Tags: windows-7, display

I'm working with/on a software that is optimized for screens in portrait mode and some of the features rely on this orientation, so things won't work or won't be displayed correctly with landscape orientation.

In the Windows 7 settings, I can rotate the screen content which works fine, but I'd have to physically rotate my screen to make this useful, which I unfortunately can't. Rotating my head isn't the most ergonomic solution either.

So a tool to rotate the screen content and display the result in portrait mode would be useful. From the software's view, it should "see" a resolution of e.g. 1080x1920 on a 1920x1080 display. Of course, there would be some scaling drawbacks or vertical scrollbars involved as the vertical resolution is much smaller, but I could live with that.

Is there something like this? Of course, feel free to recommend alternative solutions.

I've asked the [question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/931387/is-there-a-tool-to-rotate-screen-content-without-the-need-to-physically-rotate-t), but referred to this site because it is more on-topic here.